# Event listener not attaching to all element but attach to last one only in for loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, addeventlistener

I am trying to add an event listener on the thumbnail container and it is not attaching to all elements, but instead always attaching to the last one.

I tried to put the content of for loop in an anonymous function but it is also not working.

```
const getThumbnail = async (skipIndex) => {
  if (typeof skipIndex === "number") {
        const { files } = await fetchData(`/getNumber/${skipIndex}`, null, true);
        const { length } = files;

        if (length !== 0 && files) 
        {
            APP.skipIndex += length;

            for (let index = 0; index < length; index++) {
                const element = files[index];
                const { length } = element;
                const [videoName] = element.filename.split("_");
                const { _id } = element;

                if (!length <= 0) {
                    const { mimetype } = element.metadata;
                    const data = await fetchData(`/getThumbnail/${_id}`, null, false);
                    const thumbnailDataString = getBase64(mimetype, data);
                    addVideoThumbnail(thumbnailDataString, videoName, index, _id);
                }
                else 
                {
                    const defaultUrl = "../img/default.png";
                    addVideoThumbnail(defaultUrl, videoName, index, _id);
                }

                const tCon = elementById(_id);
                addEvent(tCon);
            }
        }
        else {
            APP.skipIndex = false;
        }
    }
    else {
        console.log("else first");
    }
};



const addEvent = (tCon) => {

    console.log("add event");

    const [thumbnail, name, deleteSpan] = tCon.children;
    const { id } = tCon;

    deleteSpan.addEventListener("click", async () => {
        const postData = {
            method: "DELETE",
        };

        const res = await fetchData(`/deleteFile/${id}`, postData, true);
        res.result ? showAlert("success", false) : showAlert("failure", false);
    });

    const opacityChange = (status) => {
        status ? thumbnail.classList.add("opacity-50") : thumbnail.classList.remove("opacity-50");
    };

    const sameFunc = (opacity, visible) => {
        opacityChange(opacity);
        changeClass(name, visible);
        changeClass(deleteSpan, visible);
    };

    deleteSpan.addEventListener("mouseover", () => opacityChange(true));
    name.addEventListener("mouseover", () => opacityChange(true));

    tCon.addEventListener("mouseover", () => sameFunc(true, false));
    tCon.addEventListener("mouseout", () => sameFunc(false, true));
    tCon.addEventListener("click", () => watchVideo(id));
    tCon.addEventListener("touchmove", () => sameFunc(true, false));
    tCon.addEventListener("touchend", () => sameFunc(false, true));
};
```

I think it's a **closure** problem.

Sorry if this is weird, I am a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a day finding so much about it. I found that using a *setTimeout* with 0 milliseconds is solving my problem.

 **How** :-
when you set milliseconds to 0 it means to you want to fire it at last.
so when my for loop end. all setTimeout fire's one by one and pass _id to addEvent function.

 **So Current Code is This** :-

```js
const getThumbnail = async (skipIndex) => {
  if (typeof skipIndex === "number") {
    APP.hitted = true;
    const { files } = await fetchData(`/getNumber/${skipIndex}`, null, true);
    const { length } = files;
    if (length !== 0 && files) {
      files.forEach(async (element, index) => {
        const originalIndex = index + APP.skipIndex;
        const { length, _id } = element;
        const [videoName] = element.filename.split("_");
        if (!length <= 0) {
          const { mimetype } = element.metadata;
          const data = await fetchData(`/getThumbnail/${_id}`, null, false);
          const thumbnailDataString = getBase64(mimetype, data);
          addVideoThumbnail(thumbnailDataString, videoName, originalIndex, _id);
        } // else this will fire
        else {
          const defaultUrl = "../img/default.png";
          addVideoThumbnail(defaultUrl, videoName, originalIndex, _id);
        }
        setTimeout(() => addEvent(_id.slice()), 0);
      });
      APP.skipIndex += length;
    } // else this will fire
    else APP.skipIndex = false;
  }
  setTimeout(() => {
    APP.hitted = false;
  }, 1000);
};
const addEvent = (id) => {
  const tCon = elementById(id);
  const [thumbnail, name, deleteSpan] = tCon.children;
  deleteSpan.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    const postData = {
      method: "DELETE",
    };
    const res = await fetchData(`/deleteFile/${id}`, postData, true);
    if (res.result) {
      tCon.remove();
      showAlert("success", false);
    } // else this will fire
    else showAlert("failure", false);
  });
  // to add or remove opacity-50 class from thumbnail
  const opacityChange = (status) => {
    status
      ? thumbnail.classList.add("opacity-50")
      : thumbnail.classList.remove("opacity-50");
  };
  const sameFunc = (opacity, visible) => {
    opacityChange(opacity);
    changeClass(name, visible);
    changeClass(deleteSpan, visible);
  };
  deleteSpan.addEventListener("mouseover", () => opacityChange(true));
  name.addEventListener("mouseover", () => opacityChange(true));
  tCon.addEventListener("mouseover", () => sameFunc(true, false));
  tCon.addEventListener("mouseout", () => sameFunc(false, true));
  thumbnail.addEventListener("click", () => watchVideo(id));
  tCon.addEventListener("touchmove", () => sameFunc(true, false));
  tCon.addEventListener("touchend", () => sameFunc(false, true));
};
```

You can also check out ***source code*** of this file or project to know more about it in detail by [click here](https://github.com/YashLodhi-16/Local/tree/master)

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is most likely a closure problem. The tCon you give at the addEvent(tCon) call is sent as a reference and therefore as the loop progresses and the value of tCon changes, it will reflect on the references as well.

Consider changing your addEvent function like so:

```
const addEvent = (element_id) => {
    const tCon = elementById(element_id);
```

And then calling the `addEvent` like this:

```
addEvent(_id.slice());
```

`_id.slice()` creates a copy of `_id` and sends that copy to the addEvent function. This copy of `_id` should now be sent as a value to the `addEvent` function.

Afterwards, inside the `addEvent` function, we use that copy of the `_id` to get the element by id into the `tCon` variable.

I can't 100% verify that this works, so just try it out and see what happens.

Edit:

Instead of `addEvent(_id.slice())`, you could use [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE):

```
((id) => {
    addEvent(id);
})(_id);
```

Comment: i use your suggestion but its not working it still adding event listener to last element

Comment: @yashlodhi Hmm. Well I edited my answer with another thing you can try.

Comment: i just end up with store id in  ids (temporary array) and use a foreach loop with ids to fire addEvent function and this works!

Comment: Variables declared with `const` are block scoped, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @FelixKling Hmm, interesting. I guess you learn something new every day!

Comment: well i just put **addEvent** function inside a _setTimeout_  and everything just work fine
 ` setTimeout(() =>   addEvent(_id), 100);`